# How to use Ion library within a service?

Tags: android, download, android-service, android-context, android-ion

I'm trying to make my Android app download some files from internet and I'm using a service to do this task with the help of Ion lib, but I need to provide a context: 
`Ion.with(context)`...

How can I do that?

Comment: please provide the code you have already

Comment: thank you YakovL for your reply, I think I found the answer for my question. I didn't know that Service is inherited from Context. so Ion.th(this) will work

Comment: I see. Would be nice of you if you share your solution in a form of an answer (a bit more detailed than the comment) and accept your answer once you can do so (SO only allows that after 2 days, if I'm not mistaken)